# symfony2 crud generating: unable to find template

Tags: symfony, twig, generator

Creating controller with

```
app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

ends up with an error:

```
[Twig_Error_Loader]

Unable to find template "crud/views/layout.html.twig.twig"
(looked into: ...\vendor\sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command/../Resources/skeleton,
...\vendor\sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command/../Resources).
```

In the requested directory I can't find a template like "crud/views/layout.html.twig.twig".

Any help appreciated,

Comment: try to delete the vendor dir and reinstall via `php composer.phar install`

Comment: Reinstalling SensioBundle helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use *find text in the files* with Netbeans or Notepad++ for searching next string:

```
layout.html.twig.twig
```

maybe you have this template name in any parent templates or your controllers.
Or for test, try to create `crud/views/layout.html.twig.twig` template and generate crud again.